# What could $civicrm_root setting in civicrm.settings.php appears ignored?

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

I'm running 4.7.27 and regardless of what I set the $civicrm_root to, the hints in resource URL and file path setting pages give quite unrelated values for civicrm.root. I am also unable to set the resource URL to anything but the prefilled value (editing it and submitting does nothing).

Consequently it looks like some override is at work. However, I've checked the civicrm.settings.php many times and I'm unable to find such an override.

What could be causing this? Everything displays fine, except for loading of the CKEditor js-files. But the fact that editing civicrm.settings.php doesn't do anything scares me. I've verified that the file is indeed the correct one (removing it breaks the site), and that even removing the $civicrm_root entirely does nothing.

From the settings:

```
global $civicrm_root;

$civicrm_root = '/foo/www/sites/abc.foo.se/current/web/app/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';
if (!defined('CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR')) { 
   define( 'CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR', '/foo/www/sites/abc.foo.se/shared/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/');
}
```

Comment: You may wish to look at the discussion on Mattermost: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/z4w1fmay7fna5ggqbug57ticbw

Answer (score 1):

There might two settings defined for CiviCRM. Can look if you have any other civicrm.settings.php file located in different folder?

```
 The recommended location is wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php.

 The deprecated location, still supported as of April 2017, was wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
```

HTH

Pradeep